# How to update state of an array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this array of visibility of my buttons. I am saving state of those buttons in a state.

```
this.state = {
  score: 0,
  status: "",
  userSelected: "",
  computerSelected: "",
  visibility: [true, true, true]
};
```

I want to update value of visibility array index wise. I tried to do like below but it doesn't update, it keep adding new elements in an array instead of update value of an array.

```
var arrayvar = this.state.visibility.slice();
if (
  (user === "Rock" && computer === "Paper") ||
  (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock")
) {
  arrayvar.push(true, true, false); // here set 1st and 2nd to true and 3rd to false
} else if (
  (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
  (user === "Scissors" || computer === "Rock")
) {
  arrayvar.push(true, false, true);
} else if (
  (user === "Paper" && computer === "Scissors") ||
  (user === "Scissors" || computer === "Paper")
) {
  arrayvar.push(false, true, true);
} else if (user === "Rock" && computer === "Rock") {
  arrayvar.push(true, false, false);
} else if (user === "Paper" && computer === "Paper") {
  arrayvar.push(false, true, false);
} else if (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Scissors") {
  arrayvar.push(false, false, true);
}
this.setState({ visibility: arrayvar });
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this in `reactjs` ?

Comment: But that's what [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I see. do you know whats a way to update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**array.push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control) will always push the new values in `array`, it will not update the existing values.

You need to write it like this:

```
arrayvar = [];                     //create a variable, don't need to copy the state values here


arrayvar = [true, true, false];    // assign new array inside conditions

this.setState({
    visibility: arrayvar           //then update the state visibility array
})
```

You don't need to create a copy of `state array` because, you are updating the whole `array` not the specific value of the `array`, simply create a variable:

```
arrayvar = [];
```

Full code:

```
var arrayvar = [];
if ( (user === "Rock" && computer === "Paper") || (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock")) {
    arrayvar = [true, true, false];
} else if ((user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") || (user === "Scissors" || computer === "Rock")) {
    arrayvar = [true, false, true]
} else if ((user === "Paper" && computer === "Scissors") || (user === "Scissors" || computer === "Paper")) {
    arrayvar = [false, true, true];
} else if (user === "Rock" && computer === "Rock") {
    arrayvar = [true, false, false];
} else if (user === "Paper" && computer === "Paper") {
  arrayvar = [false, true, false];
} else if (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Scissors") {
  arrayvar = [false, false, true];
}
this.setState({ visibility: arrayvar });
```

Comment: What if I was not updating complete visibility array then do i need to clone then how to do ?

Comment: in that case first create a copy, use item index to update the specific value then update the state, like this: `let visibility = this.state.visibility.slice();  visibility[item_index] = value; this.setState({visibility})`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayank +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

By the way,

```
var arrayvar = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    .map(
        k => computer === k || user === k
    );
```

May well replace the whole if-then cascade you wrote.

Comment: How will it work ? can you please explain. looks like best approach +1

Comment: It maps each 'key'  in an array onto 'whether computer or user chose it`.